# how can I save a photo with an specific name in C# xamarin forms android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to put a name to an image when I save it in my folder.

this is my code:

```
var file2 = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                SaveToAlbum = true
            });
```

this take a photo and then save it in /Pictures but I need to name it. by default the name is something like this "IMG_20220818_17585.jpg"

how could I save it with a diferent name?

Thank you very much!

Comment: have you tried setting the `Name` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION / UPDATE**

this resolved my problem.

```
var file2 = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                Name = "Name that I want",
                SaveToAlbum = true
            });
```

Comment: Please mark your reply as an answered so that it will help others who have similar problems will get help from here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes! I do that normally, but I wasn't able to do it until today. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to [CrossMedia](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#usage)'s documentation on directory and file name, I believe you only need to assign a value to the "Name" property in your StoreCameraMediaOptions:

```
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
{
    Directory = "Sample",
    Name = "test.jpg"
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I did something like that to resolve my problem!